# How to create a group of options in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to store URLs that are entered in a plugin page to the database and then retrieve them in another function.

The number and name of the URL changes so I was wondering if there was a way to add them to a group and then get all options from that group.

Is there a `create_options_group` function or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

You can save them all in one option. If you pass an array to `update_option()` WP will automatically serialize the data. From there, anytime you retrieve the option with `get_option()`, WP will automatically put everything back into an array.